# How do I get the index of an array and "stick it" when moving to another array?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, excel, list

I'm sorry for the confusing question but feel free to edit it.

My goal is to make an Attendance Checker using Python 3.x while associating it to an excel file.

I am a beginner in Python 3.x

Here is the code:

```
import openpyxl

wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook("A:\\Names.xlsx")
ws = wb_obj.active

def diff(first, second) -> type(None):
    return list(result)


class_list_array = []
for i in ws.iter_rows(max_row=47):
    for cell in i:
        cell = cell.value
        class_list_array.append(cell)

x = ""
end = 0
value = 0
while end < 47:
    value += 1 
    up = value
    x = "B" + str(up)
    ws[x] = "PRESENT"
    end += 1



#ws[count] = "PRESENT"
wb_obj.save(filename = "A:\\Names.xlsx")

print(class_list_array)
present_names = input("Who are present? \n")
present_names_array = present_names.split(", ")
present_names_array = [row.upper() for row in present_names_array] 
print("PRESENT")
print(present_names_array)
print("")

a = set(present_names_array) - set(class_list_array)
b = set(class_list_array) - set(present_names_array)
result = a.union(b)

print("ABSENT/LATE")
print(diff(class_list_array, present_names_array))

#result = list(result)
#for rows in result:
#    x = class_list_array.index(rows)
#    cell = ws.cell(row = x, column = 2)
#    cell.value = "ABSENT/LATE"
wb_obj.save(filename = "A:\\Names.xlsx")
```

The hashtags are me trying to figure out how do I get the index of a column in Excel.

What the code does is ask for the user's input. First, the present. Then, it compares the Present to the Class List Array; the result is the absent/late.

PROBLEM: I can't figure out how to add the label "ABSENT/LATE" next to the elements in the Absent/Late Array in Excel. For example, the array of Absent/Late is ["Bob", "Louise"] and Present is ["John"]

```
My desired result in an excel file is:
BOB | ABSENT/LATE
JOHN | PRESENT
Louise| ABSENT/LATE
```

MY "SOLUTION" but can't figure out how to do it: Get the index of the Absent/Late Array based on the Class List Array. For example, Class List Array ["Bob", "John", "Louise"]. Index is [0, 1, 2]
In the Absent/List Array ["Bob, "Louise"]; their index is still attached so Bob is 0 and Louise is 2

Doing so, using the for loop I hashtagged, I can associate x = rows as rows = to the index of Bob and Louise at the original Class List Array: 0 & 2.

Again, this is my wild guess. Currently learning Python 3.x. Sorry for being a noob.